# Unable to delete a data flow in Azure Data factory in git mode

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, etl

I have an azure data factory data flow that I have to delete. I have to because in order to publish my latest data factory changes, I need to clear the validations on this data flow. However, I can't delete it nor can I update it to another name or fix the validations. When I save any of those changes, it says it failed to save, or gives the below error:

```
Failed to save All resources.
Error: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The path '//dataflow/currentplan.json' does not exist at commit 'b04d8869c860afc6ac801503d7a76cd438a8f91f'\r\nParameter name:
```

Yet when I refresh, I see that data flow there and I can click into it and see the flow objects.

Any tips on how I can get around this? I'd try an earlier commit but I can't find a way to check out an earlier one like you would with normal git. I also would just copy my good data flows to another data factory and start there, but I have no idea how to do that. Has anyone encountered this issue with data factory?

Thank you!

Tried deleting as normal, tried editing the json file for the data flow.

Answer (score 0):

Go the git branch---> dataflow ---> yourfile.json ( delete directly from there )

Now if you refresh datafactory ,you wont see the dataflow anymore and if you continue to work on same branch ,adf_publish also gets updated if you are in collab branch .